# Hidden property in Django 1.7 admin BaseInlineFormSet

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model in my project which is rendered as an inline of an other model.
The inline model has a *property* (**not a field**) that I need in my template for a particular check, but I don't want it shown as a field. I can't find a way to make such field rendered as hidden, so that the entire `<TD>` disappears.

I've both tried with `Meta` class:

```
class MyFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'to_be_hidden_property': forms.HiddenField,
        }
```

and with `add_fields` method:

```
class MyFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):

    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(MyFormset, self).add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields["to_be_hidden_property"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

but both failed. First attempt simply gets ignored, while second one leads to a KeyError exception (field doesn't exist).

I'm open to suggestions, as I'd really hate to have to hide it via JS.

EDIT (adding `admin.TabularInline` code):

```
class AssegnamentoCommessaConsulenzaInline(admin.TabularInline):

    formset = AssegnamentoCommessaConsulenzaFormset
    model = AssegnamentoCommessaConsulenza
    template = 'admin/commessa/edit_inline/assegnamentocommessaconsulenza_tabular.html'
    extra = 0

    readonly_fields = (
        'get_fase',
        'get_configuration_link_inline',
        'numero_erogazioni_effettuate',  # Field to hide
    )

    class Media:
        js = ('useless things', )
        css = {'all': ('even less useful things', )}
```

---

EDIT (to explain what I've tried after @Alasdair's suggestion):

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

class MyFormAbstract(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyFormAbstract, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['to_be_hidden_property'] = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
            initial=self.instance.to_be_hidden_property
        )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

MyFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    MyMainModel,
    MyInlineModel,
    form=MyFormAbstract
)
```

This whole thing seems to get silently ignored. There are no errors, but the property is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subclassing `BaseInlineFormSet`, you might find it easier to [customize the model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-form).

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['property_field'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=self.instance.property_field)

MyInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(MyMainModel, MyModel, form=MyForm)
```

Note that all this does is add the hidden field to the form, you will have to add any additional processing you want.

Comment: I've edited my post to show my attempt. As you can see, it doesn't seem to solve the issue...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *This whole thing seems to get silently ignored. There are no errors, but the property is still there.* I've tested my example above, and it appears to work.

Comment: I mean that it just seems to have no effects at all. Did you try with a property or with an actual db field?

Comment: I am using a property, as you stated in your question. What does your template look like? Showing your actual code instead of an example might help.

Comment: I could post my template code, but I've just tried using the base template for inlines (tabular.html) and things don't change, so I guess it's not a template related issue. I'm adding the TabularInline code from admin.py, but I'm not sure it will help much.

Comment: Ah, I didn't spot the `django-admin` tag in your question. That makes it trickier, I don't have any suggestions at the moment I'm afraid.